# SQL Generate script of schedule job

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have many schedule jobs in SQL Agent. I want to create backup weekly/monthly so that when any issue occur with server, I will create all jobs again by script instead of creating each job manually.

I know that from SSMS we can generate that kind of script, but my question is how I can generate script using t-sql for each schedule job?

Comment: If you're familiar with SMO objects, they can be used for this.  See this link for details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Using T-SQL it's unnecessarily tedious -- you have to scrape the details from `msdb.dbo.sysjobs` and `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps` and synthesize commands from them. Using a scheduled PowerShell script (which should also be possible from a job) it's fairly easy: `dir sqlserver:\sql\localhost\default\JobServer\Jobs |% { $_.Script() }` will script them all at once, redirect to files as needed. I've never tried getting this to work on a server, though; some installation may be required to make the `SqlServer` module available.

Comment: Note that a backup of `msdb` will also back up the jobs -- restoring `msdb` is not something that should be done on a whim, or just to get the jobs back, but it's a good option to have in any case.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 msdb stored procs you can call for this:

- **sp_add_job** to create a a new job
- **sp_add_jobstep** to add a new step in a job
- **sp_add_jobschedule** to add a schedule to a job
- **sp_add_jobserver** to add the job to a specific server

Please read this article for a more detailed explanation:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3052/simple-way-to-create-a-sql-server-job-using-tsql/

Comment: I am not going to create job, I am going to create script for existing job. :(

Comment: if you have a "suggestion", add a comment, don't enter it as a answer.